# Method find in ReactiveMongo is deprecated. 0.20.3

Tags: scala, reactivemongo

I am upgrading reactive mongo "0.17.1-play26" to "0.20.3" but, It is giving lots of error. I am accessing MongoDB to find the data. It gave me the above error. plz help

Here is the statement which I am giving

```
stdntcollection.find(query,Option(select)).cursor[studentDetails]().collect[List(-1,Cursor.FailOnError[List[studentDetails]]())`
```

`studentdetails` is a case class. which have a structure like

```
     case class studentDetails(
         roll: Option[String], 
         subjct: String    
     )

     object studentDetails {
         implicit val studentDetailsReads: Reads[studentDetails] = (
             (__ \ "roll").readNullable[String] and
             (__ \ "subjct").read[String])(studentDetails.apply _)

         implicit val studentDetailsWrites: Writes[studentDetails] = (
             (__ \ "roll").writeNullable[String] and
             (__ \ "subjct").write[String](unlift(studentDetails.unapply))
     }
```

Here is the error:

> not enough arguments for method find: (implicit swriter: stdntcollection.pack.Writer[play.api.libs.json.JsObject], implicit pwriter: stdntcollection.pack.Writer[scala.collection.Map[String,Int]])reactivemongo.api.collections.GenericQueryBuilder[stdntcollection.pack.type]. Unspecified value parameters swriter, pwriter.

Comment: Please format properly your question

Comment: it's my first post, I trying to be more clear

Answer (score 0):

I guess your are using collection with JSON, and that there is missing implicits for `select` you pass as projection second argument. As indicated in the [documentation](http://reactivemongo.org/releases/0.1x/documentation/json/overview.html):

```
import reactivemongo.play.json._
```

> Note #1: [Recommended naming](https://docs.scala-lang.org/style/naming-conventions.html) of case class is not respected by `studentDetails`
>
> Note #2: `JSONCollection` will probably be removed from release 1.0, with a simpler JSON supported provided by the new conversions.

Comment: package object json in package json is deprecated (since 0.19.2): Will be replaced reactivemongo.play.json.compat._ from reactivemongo-play-json-compat

Comment: import play.modules.reactivemongo._

Comment: import reactivemongo.play.json._

Comment: import reactivemongo.play.json.collection._

Comment: import play.api.libs.json._

Comment: If you use `reactivemongo-play-json-compat` *do not* use a `JSONCollection`

Comment: Then, what i will use instead of JSONCollection, as i am using JSONCollection all over my code

Comment: `BSONCollection`

Comment: I don't want to use BSONCollection, I want to work with JSON. so, plz tell me how to resolve my problem

Comment: Using existing JSON codec doesn't mean using the JSONCollection, which has previously indicated will no longer be available. Using JSON means using the JSON/BSON conversions provided by the combat lib, for the parameters/results to/from the BSONCollection.

Comment: so, you mean to say that. I need to use bson, and then I convert it to get an output as JSON. am right? actually things are getting tricky.

Comment: can you plz elaborate on yourself by giving me some examples including imports too.

Comment: No, please read carefully and have look at the examples. I said that you do not need to use `JSONCollection` (that doesn't offer any specific operation) to benefit from "automatic" JSON/BSON conversions (provided the appropriate codecs instances are available).